# KTable to KTable inner join doesn't yield all expected results (possible co-partitioning issue)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Given that I have a topology which looks like this:

**In plain english:**

- Input `A_Value` with `A_Id`

  - Becomes `KTable<A_Id, A_Value>` `store-A_Value-by-A_Id-ktable`
- Stream Input `B_Value` with `B_Id`

  - `mapValues`: in order to surrogate the tombstone into a valid `B_Value` with a `deleted: true` property
  - `groupByKey`: `KGroupedStream<B_Id, B_Value>`

    - `reduce`: in here, if the **new** `B_Value.isDeleted() == true`, return **old** `B_Value` with `deleted: true`, that's important because I'll need the `A_Id` property later
    - Becomes `KTable<B_Id, B_Value>` `store-B_Value-by-B_Id-ktable`
- Input `KTable<B_Id, B_Value>`

  - `toStream`
  - `groupBy`: `B_Value.getA_Id()`

    - `recude`: `KTable<A_Id, B_Value>`
- Join `KTable<A_Id, B_Value>` and `KTable<A_Id, A_Value>`: `KTable<A_Id, Pair<B_Value, A_Value>>`

  - `toStream`
  - `map`: if `B_Value.isDeleted() == true` then propagate a `KeyValue<B_Id, null` (tombstone), otherwise `KeyValue<B_Id, Pair<B_Value, A_Value>>`

    - `to`: output topic

**In Kafka Streams topology:**

*Sub-topology: 0*

```
Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [input-A_value-A_key])
  --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000001
Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000011 (topics: [input-B_value-A_key])
  --> KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000008
Processor: KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000008 (stores: [store-B-by-A_key-ktable])
  --> KTABLE-JOINTHIS-0000000013
  <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000011
Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000001 (stores: [store-A-by-A_key-ktable])
  --> KTABLE-JOINOTHER-0000000014
  <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
Processor: KTABLE-JOINOTHER-0000000014 (stores: [store-B-by-A_key-ktable])
  --> KTABLE-MERGE-0000000012
  <-- KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000001
Processor: KTABLE-JOINTHIS-0000000013 (stores: [store-A-by-A_key-ktable])
  --> KTABLE-MERGE-0000000012
  <-- KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000008
Processor: KTABLE-MERGE-0000000012 (stores: [])
  --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015
  <-- KTABLE-JOINTHIS-0000000013, KTABLE-JOINOTHER-0000000014
Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000016
  <-- KTABLE-MERGE-0000000012
Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000016 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000017
  <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015
Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000017 (topic: output-AB_aggregate-B_key)
  <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000016
```

*Sub-topology: 1*

```
Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002 (topics: [input-B_value-B_key])
  --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000003
Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000003 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000004
  <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002
Processor: KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000004 (stores: [store-B_value-B_key-ktable])
  --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000005
  <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000003
Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000005 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
  <-- KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000004
Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000007
  <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000005
Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000007 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000010
  <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000010 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000009
  <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000007
Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000009 (topic: input-B_value-A_key)
  <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000010
```

Important to know constraints that led to this topology:

- Records from A are *never* deleted
- Records from B are leading the deletion, thus propagating tombstones to the output topic
- Topic with A records is about 10x bigger than topic with B records
- Input `B` has in its value the `A_Id`
- Timestamps from input A cannot be trusted, neither the broker ingested one, since there was a batch loaded at once

All the intended behavior listed below works really well for new incoming data:

- Record A arrives, join output works
- Record B arrives, join output works
- Record B Tombstone arrives, output tombstone works

The problem observed happens during the first bootstrap of the streamer, where the number of joins expected of i.e. 1000, is actually 70, if the streamer keeps running, no inconsistency appears.
The number 1000 comes from unique `B` records which have matching `A` records in my original topic data, I've also come to check whether all my changelog stores had the correct data after the transformations, and they do.

What have I tried?

- Set commit interval to 0
- Disable cache
- Use `WallclockTimestampExtractor` for both input topics
- Use custom `TimestampExtractor` for both input topics which always returns `0`
- Use a custom `ValueTransformerWithKeySupplier` instead of the inner join which has a Ponctuation (Both Wall and record time based) of 1 seconds
- A test I did was to set all my topics to 1 partition, then I actually have all the desired joins, since I'm generating the KTables and such, I don't understand why I might have a wrong co-partitioning

I'm  not running out of things to try, I could still try to go deeper but I'd like to see if I'm making other mistakes in my approach first, thanks for any help.

Comment: Another test I've done now was to convert all my data to a single partition, just to see what would happen, now I got all the messages I was expecting, by re-keying the topic I'd expect the co-partition to be successful, could that be wrong?

Comment: Could you add source code used to build your topology?